# Using a static field in a unit test throws Null reference exception

Tags: c#, mstest

```
[TestClass]
public class SearchTreeTest
{
    static IOiContext iContext;
    static SearchTree searchTree;

    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void InitializeContext(TestContext context)
    {
        //do some stuff here ....
        //initialize searchTree here
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void SomeMethod_SomeState_SomeExpectation()
    {
        //My test will fail because an error will be thrown here.
        parameters = searchTree.FindParameters(...)
        ...
    }
}
```

I am using a static field, searchTree, in my unit test because I want all of my tests to have access to this field. I initialize it in the method with the ClassInitialize attribute so that it should be ran before any of my unit tests. However, when I use the field in any of the test methods, it fails because a NullReferenceException is thrown.

I am new to unit testing and also relatively new to c# as well but I figured that this would be quite a simple fix. When searching online though, I couldn't find anything about what I may be doing wrong. Any suggestions?

**Edit**

```
    [TestClass]
    public class SearchTreeTest
    {
        static IXiContext iContext;
        static SearchTree searchTree;

        [ClassInitialize]
        public static void InitializeContext(TestContext context)
        {
            string serverUrl = "http://192.168.3.10:58080/XiServices/ServerDiscovery";
            //private ServiceEndpoint sep;
            IXiEndpointDiscovery iEndpointDiscovery = new XiEndpointDiscovery(serverUrl) as IXiEndpointDiscovery;
            ServiceEndpoint sep = iEndpointDiscovery.GetServiceEndpointsByBinding("IResourceManagement", typeof(NetTcpBinding)).First();

            iContext = XiContext.Initiate(sep, iEndpointDiscovery.ServerEntry,
                    300000, (uint)ContextOptions.EnableJournalDataAccess +
                    (uint)ContextOptions.EnableAlarmsAndEventsAccess + (uint)ContextOptions.EnableDataAccess,
                    (uint)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.LCID,
                    Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

            ServiceEndpoint readsep = iEndpointDiscovery.GetServiceEndpointsByBinding("IRead", typeof(NetTcpBinding)).First();
            IXiEndpointBase readEndpoit = iContext.OpenEndpoint(readsep, 30000, new TimeSpan(5000));           

            Node ai = new Node("AI");
            Node ti_101 = new Node("TI-101/AI1/PV.CV");
            Node di_101 = new Node("DI-101/DI1/");
            Node ai_101 = new Node("AI-101/AI1/PV.CV");
            Node aic_30 = new Node("AIC_30");
            Node di_101_pv = new Node("DI-101/DI1/PV_D.CV");
            Node di_101_out = new Node("DI-101/DI1/OUT_D.CV");
            Node aic_301 = new Node("AIC_301/AI1/PV.CV");
            Node aic_302 = new Node("AIC_302/AI/");
            Node aic_302_pv = new Node("AIC_302/AI1/PV.CV");
            Node aic_302_out = new Node("AIC_302/AI1/OUT.CV");

            searchTree = new SearchTree("DA:/../MODULES/", iContext);
            searchTree.Root.Children.Add(ai);
            searchTree.Root.Children.Add(ti_101);
            searchTree.Root.Children.Add(di_101);
            ai.Children.Add(ai_101);
            ai.Children.Add(aic_30);
            aic_30.Children.Add(aic_301);
            aic_30.Children.Add(aic_302);
            aic_302.Children.Add(aic_302_pv);
            aic_302.Children.Add(aic_302_out);
            di_101.Children.Add(di_101_pv);
            di_101.Children.Add(di_101_out);
        }

        [ClassCleanup]
        public static void CleanUpContext()
        {
            iContext.Dispose();
            iContext = null;
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void staticMethod()
        {
            //I added this just so see what would happen.
            Assert.IsNull(searchTree);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void FindParameters_SearchRoot_ReturnsListOfParameter()
        {
            var parameters = searchTree.FindParameters("DA:/../MODULES/");
            var count = parameters.Count;
            var paths = from p in parameters
                    select p.Path;

            var actualPaths = paths.ToList();
            Assert.AreEqual(4, count, count.ToString());
            string[] expectedPaths =  
            {
                "DA:/../MODULES/",
                "DA:/../MODULES/AREA_A",
                "DA:/../MODULES/AREA_1",
                "DA:/../MODULES/BOILER_3"
            };

            foreach (string p in expectedPaths)
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(actualPaths.Contains(p), actualPaths[2]);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit 2**

See the image below. When I debug my test, it crashes when I get to the point indicated in the image below. SearchTree is a class that has a property called Root which is of type Node. Node has a property called Children which is a List. I didn't post this earlier because I could not connect to the server from a remote machine when debugging for some reason.

[image: Debug session]

**Solution**

The issue was not with the searchTree object itself. It was the properties (Children property) of the searchTree which were throwing the NullReferenceException.

```
searchTree = new SearchTree("DA:/../MODULES/", iContext);
searchTree.Root.Children = new List<Node>();
searchTree.Root.Children.Add(ai);
searchTree.Root.Children.Add(ti_101);
searchTree.Root.Children.Add(di_101);
ai.Children = new List<Node>();
ai.Children.Add(ai_101);
ai.Children.Add(aic_30);
aic_30.Children = new List<Node>();
aic_30.Children.Add(aic_301);
aic_30.Children.Add(aic_302);
aic_302.Children = new List<Node>();
aic_302.Children.Add(aic_302_pv);
aic_302.Children.Add(aic_302_out);
di_101.Children = new List<Node>();
di_101.Children.Add(di_101_pv);
di_101.Children.Add(di_101_out);
```

Comment: where are you constructing it?

Comment: also it is a bad practice to use static fields for unit tests - they don't need to be.

Comment: Are you sure that your initialization of the `searchtree` works correctly? Debug it in case of uncertainty.

Comment: @DanielA.White I am constructing it in InitializeContext (the method with the ClassInitialize attribute).

Comment: please show that code!

Comment: sure, give me minute

Comment: The code has been posted ... or as much of it as I think is necessary.

Comment: Another reason why I made it static by the way was because I got an error in VS indicating that InitializeContext had the wrong signature and needed be static. So I made the fields static as well.

Comment: In the code you show, you *don't* have the method and fields as `static`. In that case, it would make sense that it doesn't get executed (and hence leaves your fields as `null`). `ClassInitialize` is for static methods that run without any instance of the test class.

Comment: @hvd sorry that was an accident. I was playing around with the code before I copied and pasted it. I assure you, in my code it is marked as static.

Answer (score -1):

You should assign a value to a variable before use it

```
static SearchTree searchTree = new SearchTree();
```

Comment: The OP is claiming that he *did* already assign a value to the field before using it. That claim might be wrong, but your answer won't help.

Comment: I do not see initialization in the code he provided. Do you?